# Can I use elevated permissions using JSOM, CSOM, or REST?

Tags: rest, csom, jsom, security, runwithelevatedprivileges

I am working with an On-Premise SharePoint 2016 farm and I am looking for some way to elevate permissions, so I don't use the logged-in user's credentials but another set of permissions that the logged in user doesn't have themselves. This is internal, so I am not looking for a 100% secure way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no way to run at elevated privileges from the client-side, and if there was a way, it would be roughly 0% secure.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, there are some ways that you might be able to work around it.

- For instance, if you can do it from a workflow, SharePoint 2010
  workflows can do an impersonation step which runs as the user who
  published the workflow.
- And SharePoint 2013 workflow can do an App
  step and be granted permissions that are beyond the current user's
  permission (I haven't actually done this one, so my description may not be entirely accurate).
- Finally, if you have the luxury of deploying server side code, you can expose limited functionality through your own web services running at elevated, and then call them from the client-side (though I'm guessing this isn't an option for you).

Comment: Thank you for the response so quickly - I have been researching this issue and your answer fits with what I saw out there and what I thought for this issue. Thanks for the confirmation